# Java TIF image reader for a 64-bit Windows system

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, tiff

I am trying to read  TIF images in Java on a 64-bit Windows machine.  I'd like to use all the memory I can as the files will be large, so a 32-bit JAI option would not work.

Is there another open source or freeware Java package out there that would read TIF files?

I looked at javax.imageio.ImageIO , but unless the doc I read is out of date, it seems this class only handles GIF, JPEG, PNG, WBMP and BMP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to read .tiff images using ImageIO, you will need a reader implementation that supports this type. There is one available in the jai_imageio.jar that is available with the JAI distribution.

Comment: I downloaded the JAI-Imageio zip and it conatins the file jai-imageio-windows-i586.exe.  How do I add this to my Netbeans ID?

Comment: I also found jai-imagei0-1.1.exe.  Would this work with 64-bit windows?  I need to use the extra memory.

Comment: You probably want to install it somewhere and copy the jar to your classpath.